# usage of issubclass

Tags: python

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.version_info
(2, 4, 4, 'final', 0)
>>> class C:
...    pass
...
>>> issubclass(C, C)
True
>>> issubclass(C, object)
False
>>> class T(object):
...    pass
...
>>> issubclass(T, T)
True
>>> issubclass(T, object)
True
>>>
```

**Question 1**> Why `C` is a subclass of `C`?

**Question 2**> what is the base class of `C`?

Thank you

// Update for Chris Morgan (At least for me, the following manual doesn't help at all)

```
>>> help(issubclass)
Help on built-in function issubclass in module __builtin__:

issubclass(...)
    issubclass(C, B) -> bool

    Return whether class C is a subclass (i.e., a derived class) of class B.
    When using a tuple as the second argument issubclass(X, (A, B, ...)),
    is a shortcut for issubclass(X, A) or issubclass(X, B) or ... (etc.).
```

Comment: On matters like `issubclass`, always remember to read the documentation first.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at [issubclass(class, classinfo)](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#issubclass) documentation

> Return true if class is a subclass (direct, indirect or virtual) of
>   classinfo. A class is considered a subclass of itself. classinfo may
>   be a tuple of class objects, in which case every entry in classinfo
>   will be checked. In any other case, a TypeError exception is raised.

and to check base class of C use [inspect.getmro(cls)](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html#inspect.getmro) function.

> Return a tuple of class cls’s base classes, including cls, in method
>   resolution order.

```
   >>> class C(object):
...        pass
...
>>> inspect.getmro(C)
(<class '__main__.C'>, <type 'object'>)
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#issubclass  From that link, "A class is considered a subclass of itself."

To answer your second question, C is an "old style" class so it isn't a subclass of object.  Include object as the superclass if you want a new style class.  See http://www.python.org/doc/newstyle/ for more info.

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#issubclass

1. A class is considered a subclass of itself.
2. C has no base class

   print C.**__*bases*__**

   ()